# use of %d 6 times gives a strange output..why?

Tags: c, output

the output of the following code on my machine is strange

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    int x = 5,y=6,sum=0;
    sum=x+y;
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", sum = x +y );
    getch();

}
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to be, u ask for the print of 6 numbers, which numbers do u expect to be printed?

Answer (score 4):

That is Undefined Behavior.

Short answer is don't do that, and enable compiler warnings to detect it at compile time `-Wformat` or `-Wall`.

Long answer:

The function declaration is:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Meaning it knows that the first argument is a format, and after that there may be some more. It scans the `format` string, and for every specifier (e.g. `%d`) it tries to remove the data from the stack corresponding to that type (in this case, an `int`).

When calling your function, you do something like:

```
push sum
push const_format_string_pointer
call printf
```

In printf, it will first read const_format_string_pointer, then sum, then whatever is on the stack before the sum. That is usually the local variables of the calling function (in this case `x`,`y`,`sum`). And indeed, it did print out 11 and 6, corresponding to `sum` and `y`. Another `%d` would likely print out 5.

The three big numbers are the things compiler added to the stack for it's own need. They have a meaning in debug mode, but it is compiler specific. Also, if you compile your code with optimizations (e.g. `-O2`), it will probably get rid of some or all of the larger numbers, and you'll end up printing stuff deeper in the stack than caller's local functions, such as caller's pushed `ebp`, or caller's return address, etc.